# Error when I try to init gentoo, Loading init ramdisk

Tags: linux, system-installation, gentoo

I installed the gento acoording to the hanbook, but when I reboot my system I've a mistake, Just I can see the following

```
Loading init ramdisk...
```

and no more.

I believe that my trouble is in the setup of my  `/etc/fstab`, because I diden't one partition to /home , /boot  I put all in the same partition, then I try to setup my `/etc/fstab` like:

```
/dev/sda6       /           ext4        noatime     0 1
/dev/SWAP       none        swap        sw          0 0
/dev/cdrom      /mnt/cdrom  auto        noauto,ro   0 0
/dev/sda5       /mnt/disco5 auto        noatime     0 0
```

**Update:**

This is the setup of my grub2, `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
menuentry 'Gentoo GNU/Linux' --class gentoo --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.14.14-gentoo ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.14-gentoo root=UUID=72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d ro  
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-3.14.14-gentoo
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Gentoo GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d' {
    menuentry 'Gentoo GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.14.14-gentoo' --class gentoo --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.14.14-gentoo-advanced-72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.14.14-gentoo ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.14-gentoo root=UUID=72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d ro  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-3.14.14-gentoo
    }
    menuentry 'Gentoo GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.14.14-gentoo (recovery mode)' --class gentoo --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.14.14-gentoo-recovery-72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.14.14-gentoo ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.14.14-gentoo root=UUID=72d88d2d-9090-4aee-b18d-a02e09514a4d ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-3.14.14-gentoo
    }
}
```

So someone could tell me how to fix the problem to load the system and if my setup fstab is good?

Answer (score 3):

When I had trouble with `Loading init ramdisk...` issue, it was my HDD the was severely damaged and beyond functionality.

Looks like your HDD is broken.

If it starts initram command-line, try `fsck /dev/sda6` command, then `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` and then `update-grub`.

If it don't, reinstall the whole system, using the following partitioning:

`/    <== primary partition, 10gb root partition  with **boot flag**
/usr  <== logical partition, 24gb read-only user data
/var  <== logical partition, 26gb variable files
swap  <== logical partition, 15gb used when psysical RAM memory is full
/tmp  <== logical partition, 12gb temporary files
/home <== logical partition, 400gb home directories
the rest <== free space`

Answer (score 1):

If you have all at one partition then mount it at `/` and don't mount anything at `/boot`. Just be sure that you have installed grub and put kernel stuff to /boot directory. So if you have configured everything correctly then simply remove first line from your fstab:

```
/dev/sda6       /           ext3        noatime     0 1
/dev/SWAP       none        swap        sw          0 0
/dev/cdrom      /mnt/cdrom  auto        noauto,ro   0 0
/dev/sda5       /mnt/disco5 auto        noatime     0 0
```

And please remember that you need to set path to kernel image in grub, so for example with `grub ver. 0`, kernel located at `/boot`, `/dev/sda6` mounted at `/` and `systemd` as init, you should have something like this in `/boot/grub/grub.conf`:

```
title Gentoo Linux 3.14.14
root (hd0,5)
kernel /boot/bzImage-3.14.14-gentoo root=/dev/sda6 rootfstype=ext3 init=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but not works, I'm using `grub2`

Comment: @CristianChaparroA. jimmij neglected to mention that `/dev/SWAP` should point to a swap partition as `/dev/SWAP` is a place holder and doesn't exist.

Comment: @CristianChaparroA. Also use grub legacy until after you get this configured.  Once it's configured I'll help you switch